# Closure with phantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using phantomJS to populate data from a service.  In the code below sessionToken is set but I can't access it outside of the function scope.  I know I need to use a closure but I haven't been able to get it to work.  How do I write a closure so I can access the variable outside of the scope?

```
var url = "https://securitybeta.srsplatform.com/WebServices/Srs.WebPlatform.WebServices.SrswpSite.SessionTokenService.svc/JSON/ISessionTokenServiceV2/CreateSessionToken?username=srsCore&password=[redacted]";

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
        console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
        console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

var sessionToken = 0;

var getSessionToken = page.open(url, 'get', function(status) {
    sessionToken = page.plainText;
    sessionToken = JSON.parse(sessionToken);
    sessionToken = sessionToken.Item.AuthorizedSessionToken;

    console.log('Status: ' + status + ' sessionToken = ' + sessionToken);
    //console.log(sessionToken);
    return function () {
        return sessionToken;
    }

});
sessionToken = getSessionToken();
console.log('sessionToken outside of function scope: ' + sessionToken);
```

sessionToken will be used in the following code:

```
 var webPage = require('webpage');
var vehiclePage = webPage.create();
var settings = {
    operation: "POST",
    encoding: "utf8",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "VIN": "JF2SJAAC5EG432990",
        "StandardIds": null,
        "LicenseCountry": null,
        "LicensePlate": "334 142",
        "LicenseState": "UT",
        "OdometerUnitOfMeasure": 0,
        "UnitNumber": null,
        "Year": 1994,
        "Make": "Chevrolet",
        "Model": "Camaro",
        "Engine": null,
        "Color": null,
        "Description": null
    })
};

vehiclePage.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

vehiclePage.open("https://ws-smsbeta.srsplatform.com/api/v1/Vehicle/Save?sessionToken=" + sessionToken + "&shopId=" + SHOP_ID, settings, function(status) {
    var vehicleGuid = vehiclePage.plainText;
    console.log('Status: ' + status + " " + vehicleGuid);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Either I'm missing something or I'm stating the obvious here, But, did you try and set sessionToken outside of page.open's callback ?

Comment: Setting it ouside of the page.open doesn't work.

Comment: Related: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) Answer: It's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use the variable outside the annonymous function, you must declare it before.

```
var sessionToken = {};

page.open(url, 'get', function(status) {
    sessionToken = page.plainText;
    sessionToken = JSON.parse(sessionToken);
    sessionToken = sessionToken.Item.AuthorizedSessionToken;

    console.log('Status: ' + status + ' sessionToken = ' + sessionToken);
    //console.log(sessionToken);

});

console.log('sessionToken outside of function scope: ' + sessionToken);
```

But you must understand that the `page.open` method is asynchronous, and that the last line of the code above will execute before the first line of the annonymous function passed to it. That function will be called only after the url is got, so, you can use the `.plainText` of it.

If you try to use the `.plainText` outside the function, after calling the `page.open` method, you'll have the same problem, as soon as it was not loaded yet.

---

**Update**

After your editions, you must put the other code inside a function, for example:

```
function loadVehicle(sessionToken) {
  var webPage = require('webpage');
  var vehiclePage = webPage.create();
  var settings = {
      operation: "POST",
      encoding: "utf8",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
          "VIN": "JF2SJAAC5EG432990",
          "StandardIds": null,
          "LicenseCountry": null,
          "LicensePlate": "334 142",
          "LicenseState": "UT",
          "OdometerUnitOfMeasure": 0,
          "UnitNumber": null,
          "Year": 1994,
          "Make": "Chevrolet",
          "Model": "Camaro",
          "Engine": null,
          "Color": null,
          "Description": null
      })
  };

  vehiclePage.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
      console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
      console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
  };

  vehiclePage.open("https://ws-smsbeta.srsplatform.com/api/v1/Vehicle/Save?sessionToken=" + sessionToken + "&shopId=" + SHOP_ID, settings, function(status) {
      var vehicleGuid = vehiclePage.plainText;
      console.log('Status: ' + status + " " + vehicleGuid);
      phantom.exit();
  });
}
```

And then, inside the annonymous function passed to the `page.open` method:

```
page.open(url, 'get', function(status) {
    sessionToken = page.plainText;
    sessionToken = JSON.parse(sessionToken);
    sessionToken = sessionToken.Item.AuthorizedSessionToken;
    loadVehicle(sessionToken);
});
```

Comment: Please see my edit.  I'm not sure how to integrate your solution.

Comment: @webdev5 I can't understand your edit. Please, copy your full code, and show us what you're trying to accomplish, so I can help you out with your exact problem.

Comment: Ok how's that? I had to redact the password for security reasons.

Comment: @webdev5 Your code still say nothing. Why you must use the `sessionToken` outside the closure? You didn't paste the code showing how you want to use it.